# Extract df for multi choices in dash (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, drop-down-menu, plotly-dash

I am creating a dashboard with plotly. I have a lengthy code. I am adding a piece of it below which has error.

```
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='bar1', component_property='figure'),
    Input(component_id='bank_dd', component_property='value'))


def update_figure(selected_bank):
    filter = vault['Bank']==selected_bank
    filtered_bank = vault[vault['Bank'].apply(lambda x: x == selected_bank)]
    fig = px.bar(filtered_bank, x='Bank', y='Bundles')

    return fig
```

When I use `multi = False` in dropdown the dashboard works fine. Whenever I turn the option to True the code raises following error.

`ValueError: Lengths must match to compare`

Dropdown Code is qouted below.

```
c_bank = vault['Bank'].unique()
cb_banks = dcc.Dropdown(id='bank_dd',
    options=[{"label": bank, "value": bank} for bank in c_bank],
    multi=True,
    placeholder="Select a Bank",
    style={'width':'500px','margin':'5px'})
```

I guess the issue is with filtering the data. But I cant figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to the dash package. When you use a multi dropdown, the callback inputs a list into your function, with the selected bank names. And your pandas filter thinks, that you want to compare the series with the values of the list (row wise), and not subset it. (BTW. you are not even using the filter series, and the filtered_bank is a bit overcomplicated for a simple subsetting task)

I would rather do:

```
def update_figure(selected_bank):

    filtered_bank = vault[vault['Bank'].isin(selected_bank)]

    fig = px.bar(filtered_bank, x='Bank', y='Bundles')

    return fig
```